# Publish to Apache Kafka topic from Angular front end

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to create a solution that receives events from web/desktop application that runs on kiosks. There are hundreds of kiosks spread across the country and each one generate time to time automatic events and events when something happens.

Despite this application is a locked desktop application it is built in Angular v8. I mean, it runs in a webview.

I was researching for scalable but reliable solutions and found Apache Kafka seems to be a great solution. I know there are clients for NodeJS but couldn't find any option for Angular. Angular runs on browser, for this reason, it must communicate to backend through HTTP/S.

In the end, I realized the best way to send events from Angular is to create a API that just gets message from a HTTP/S endpoint and publishes to Kafka topic. Or, is there any adapter for Kafka that exposes topics as REST?

I suppose this approach is way faster than store message in database. Is this statement correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this approach is way faster than store message in database. Is this statement correct?

It **can** be slower. Kafka is asynchronous, so don't expect to get a response in the same time-period you could perform a database read/write. (Again, would require some API, and also, largely depends on the database used)

> is there any adapter for Kafka that exposes topics as REST?

Yes, the [Confluent REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/index.html) is an Apache2 licensed product.

There is also a project [divolte/divolte-collector](https://github.com/divolte/divolte-collector) for collecting click-data and other browser-driven events.

Otherwise, as you've discovered, create your own API in any language you are comfortable with, and have it use a Kafka producer client.

Comment: Great! Thank you for confirmation, I believe I'll write an API and then, publish to topic.